# There is no "Use Normal Map" option in Unity 2D Lights

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, urp

Light script in the tutorial

[image: 1]

Light script in my project

[image: 2]

Where can I find "Use Normal Map" option in the newer versions of Unity.

Answer (score 1):

In `light2D` component there's `Normal Maps` section at the bottom. You can see it has `Quality` field selected to `Disabled`. Simply click on the select and choose either `Fast` or `Accurate` to enable normal maps :)